# NP-completeness

Tags: np-complete, np, decision-problem

Q: Suppose a language A is NP-complete. Is this following statement correct?:

A: If there is a polynomial algorithm to solve A, then it can be used to all the problems in NP.

My (and some others) first thoughts were that this answer is correct. But if you look at the following picture you can see that there exist problems which are only! NP. So let's take such a problem which is not NP-complete but NP. Thus a polynomial algorithm which can be used to solve any problem which is NP-complete can not be used to solve this problem which is only! NP. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: NP-complete problems are the "hardest" problems in NP. If you can solve them you can solve all other problems in NP. This is how you should understand this figure - the level of difficulty increases vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the definition of **NP**-complete: a problem is **NP**-complete if it is in **NP** and every problem in **NP** reduces to it. So, if you have a polynomial-time algorithm for any **NP**-complete problem, you have a polynomial-time algorithm for every problem in **NP**. First, do the reduction; second, solve the complete problem.